# Calculating the circulating supply using daemon RPC

Tags: monerod, daemon, rpc, emission-curve

Is there an *easy way* to calculate the currently circulating supply using [daemon RPC calls](https://getmonero.org/resources/developer-guides/daemon-rpc.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is the `get_coinbase_tx_sum` RPC call which takes `height` and `count` parameters, and returns how many moneros were created between block `height` and block `height + count`.

So by setting `height` to zero and `count` to the current block height, you get the current money supply (the daemon might take some time to compute everything at once though).